# show msg in modal in react or javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook

I have an interesting question:
I give the user the option to upload .MSG files to the system,
Inside the DB I keep the BASE64 of the file
Now I want to introduce the .MSG inside a model
And here I am having a problem
I'm unable to convert BASE64 back
I will note that I can see extensions of PDF and WORD
Using the PDFVUWER library...

I do not have a code because I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to open an MSG file in JS? You'd need to use Outlook Object Model (`Application.Session.OpenSharedItem`), but that means JS would only be able to do that in IE.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't provide anything for drawing MSG files on the page. You need to use Outlook for opening such files if you want to display them to users. But that would be in Outlook (external application), not in the browser. Moreover, Outlook should be installed on the client side.

Instead, I'd recommend keeping the message body represented by the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property value from the OOM in the Db. In that case you will be able to display it to a user like a regular web page. Note, the message body requires some processing before saving to the Db, so embedded images could be displayed.

When MSG files are uploaded to the application you can extract the required pieces of the file such as message body and etc. for displaying it at any point later. The MSG file format is described in the [Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) section of MSDN.